# Image (not element) visibility with WebDriver

Tags: c#, html, image, webdriver

I have a clickable image and it is not visible in FireFox. I mean, there is no image, but is there is an element (and it is clickable). **FindElement(by).Displayed** returns true but there is still no image.
The question is how can I check, is this image visible?

Also, I found an error in html headers (the reason, why image is not visible), maybe there is a way to check image presence using html headers?

```
public bool IsFileIconDisplayed()
        {
            return IsElementDisplayed(By.XPath("//*[@class='SomeClass']/img"));

        }

protected bool IsElementDisplayed(By by)
        {
            return FindElement(by).Displayed;
        }
```

Comment: Well what makes it hidden/disappear/show? Does it have any CSS applied to it? When does it become hidden? (i.e on page load, when you hover over it, what?)

Comment: The answer for my question is below gave by Ashwin Prabhu, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the image have a style setting its width and height to preset values?

If not you can query the image elements' client width and height property in Javascript.

```
document.getElementById(<webElement>).getClientRects()[0].width
document.getElementById(<webElement>).getClientRects()[0].height
```

or just

```
document.getElementById(<webElement>).naturalWidth
```

With JavascriptExecutor you should be able to draw these values into your Java/C# code and conclude image loaded/not loaded based on its width/height.

Comment: No good, width and height > 0, so test thinks that image is displayed.

Comment: That's expected. don't compare against 0. Browsers have a fall back image which takes a fixed width and height usually less than 100 x 100. Rule out this case. It should be easy enough.

Comment: I tried **document.getElementsByClassName("Class")[1].children[0].width**
in chrome (where image is shown) and in FireFox (where image isn't shown), result is the same - 60px.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried document.getElementById(<webElement>).naturalWidth? (I have updated my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

This thread contains valuable information on how to check visibility of an image (pay most attention to answer provided by Dave Hunt)

[How to check URL for 404 using Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453527/how-to-check-url-for-404-using-selenium-webdriver)