# Python Selenium Webdriver: Finding 404s

Tags: python, http, selenium, webdriver

How can I determine when a URL is invalid using Python Webdriver. For instance, say I do `driver.get('http://www.google.com')`. If I then do `driver.get('anInvalidURL')`, no exception is thrown and `driver.get_source` is still Google's homepage. Is there any systematic way I can check that 'anInvalidURL' produces a 404? I am using Selenium 2.33.0 with a Webdriver powered by PhantomJS 1.9.

Answer (score -2):

Its probably a feature request that isnt yet available. Take a look at [Checking HttpResponse OK (200) with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537336/selenium-check-for-httpresponse-ok)
This might help.