# Check for response code 200 facebook webdriver & PHPUnit

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phpunit

Is there anyway to check the http response codes using the [facebook webdriver (selenium)](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) & PHPUnit?

I checked this posts [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537336/selenium-check-for-httpresponse-ok)

but was wondering if there has been an update since then.

EDIT: I have found this function! getHTTPResponseCode()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this function! getHTTPResponseCode() [API](http://facebook.github.io/php-webdriver/classes/URLChecker.html#source-view)

Now i just need to figure out how to use it.

Thanks.

Comment: URLChecker is a internal class designed for the ChromeDriver. But I think it is okay to use it like this if it is working for you.